# Apache Beam: merge branches after write outputs

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to write an apache beam pipeline where the pipeline divides into three branches, where each branch writes into BigQuery, and then merges into one to write another Bigquery Table for logging.

I am unable to merge the branches, here is the code:

```
pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(None)

p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)

ingest_data = (
        p
        | 'Start Pipeline' >> beam.Create([None])
)

p1 = (ingest_data | 'Read from and to date 1' >> beam.ParDo(OutputValueProviderFn('table1'))
        | 'fetch API data 1' >> beam.ParDo(get_api_data())
        | 'write into gbq 1' >> beam.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteToBigQuery(table='proj.dataset.table1',
                                                                   write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
                                                                   create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
                                                                   custom_gcs_temp_location='gs://project/temp')
        )

p2 = (ingest_data | 'Read from and to date 2' >> beam.ParDo(OutputValueProviderFn('table2'))
        | 'fetch API data 2' >> beam.ParDo(get_api_data())
        | 'write into gbq 2' >> beam.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteToBigQuery(table='proj.dataset.table2',
                                                                   write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
                                                                   create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
                                                                   custom_gcs_temp_location='gs://proj/temp')
     )
p3 = (ingest_data | 'Read from and to date 3' >> beam.ParDo(OutputValueProviderFn('table3'))
        | 'fetch API data 3' >> beam.ParDo(get_api_data())
        | 'write into gbq 3' >> beam.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteToBigQuery(table='proj.dataset.table3',
                                                                   write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
                                                                   create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
                                                                   custom_gcs_temp_location='gs://proj/temp')
     )
# Here I would like to merge the three branches into one: This doesn't work
merge = (p1, p2, p3) | 'Write Log' >> beam.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteToBigQuery(table='proj.dataset.table_logging',
                                                                   write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
                                                                   create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
                                                                   custom_gcs_temp_location='gs://proj/temp')
     )
```

This causes the following error:

```
AttributeError: Error trying to access nonexistent attribute `0` in write result. Please see __documentation__ for available attributes.
```

I don't care about the output of the three branches, I need to merge them just to be sure that the three previous writes are completed.

Beam inspector graph looks like this:

[image]

Comment: `WriteToBigQuery` is a sink, i.e. it (usually) does not return anything. Therefore, p1-p3 are `None`. Try definining your `p` as the result of your API request. Then use them as input for the individual tables and combine them with `beam.Flatten()` [docs](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#flatten) for the combination output.
However, it can still be that you see nothing in the combination table, or you will have a racing condition between the individual and combination tables. In this case I would recommend using a `beam.DoFn` and making a hard copy of your `p`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't merge from WriteToBigQuery, you need to redesign your pipeline:

###### Load your data

```
ingest_data = (
    p
    | 'Start Pipeline' >> beam.Create([None])
)

p1 = (ingest_data | 'Read from and to date 1' >> beam.ParDo(OutputValueProviderFn('table1'))
    | 'fetch API data 1' >> beam.ParDo(get_api_data())
    )

p2 = (ingest_data | 'Read from and to date 2' >> beam.ParDo(OutputValueProviderFn('table2'))
    | 'fetch API data 2' >> beam.ParDo(get_api_data())
 )

p3 = (ingest_data | 'Read from and to date 3' >> beam.ParDo(OutputValueProviderFn('table3'))
    | 'fetch API data 3' >> beam.ParDo(get_api_data())
 )
```

###### Start Writing each table to BigQuery

```
p1_to_bq = (p1 | 'write into bq 1' >> beam.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteToBigQuery(table='proj.dataset.table1',
                                                               write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
                                                               create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
                                                               custom_gcs_temp_location='gs://project/temp')
    )

p2_to_bq = (p2 | 'write into bq 2' >> beam.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteToBigQuery(table='proj.dataset.table2',
                                                               write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
                                                               create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
                                                               custom_gcs_temp_location='gs://project/temp')
    )

p3_to_bq = (p3 | 'write into bq 3' >> beam.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteToBigQuery(table='proj.dataset.table3',
                                                               write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
                                                               create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
                                                               custom_gcs_temp_location='gs://project/temp')
    )
```

##### Merge the data and write it into BigQuery

```
merge = (p1, p2, p3) | 'Write Log' >> beam.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteToBigQuery(table='proj.dataset.table_logging',
                                                               write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
                                                               create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
                                                               custom_gcs_temp_location='gs://proj/temp')
 )
```

Comment: Do we have any option to trigger a task only after writing is done to a Bigquery table. If yes, then how we can achieve it ?